# jQuery UI Tooltip for Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Tooltip. My problem here is that i used it for an element, which has an onclick event registered. As soon as I browse my web application via my iOS iPhone, i have to click twice on the element to trigger the onclick event. So the first click is for showing the tooltip, and the second is for the actually onclick event.

Is there a possible solution to disable tooltip for mobile? Maybe you have another idea how to deal it for the mobile version, but i don't want to demand that the user have to click twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable tooltip behavior for mobile.

```
//if mobile
$(document).tooltip('disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how iOS handles `mouseover` events. The first touch it will trigger the `mouseover` event, and the second time the `click` event. See: [Apple - handling events: Figure 6-4  One-finger gesture emulating a mouse](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7)

You may find this to be a useful workaround:

```
$('.tooltip').on('touchend', function() {
  window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

In this case on iOS the link is immediately opened on touch, while the tooltip behaviour remains on regular mouseovers.